# What if user ask two of previously asked question in his single question?

Tags: discussion, flags

If someone ask a question in which he ask two questions, that have already been asked, For example check this question: [Verify Network Connection Available and Location Services Enabled to use App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020904/verify-network-connection-available-and-location-services-enabled-to-use-app) (notice comment indicating link of previously asked question).

In that case such question can't be flagged as exact duplicate, as this is not, then what are the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple questions can be selected as duplicates (up to five technically), one for each user who casts a close vote.

Once the question gets closed those duplicates are listed at the top of the affected question.

Comment: But one user can't select two, question as duplicate, Right?

Comment: @rptwsthi that's right, one vote per user per question, those are the rules :)